# VB.net Option Strict, listview.items.add(itm.clone) Overload

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem, overload-resolution, option-strict

In VB.net (2012) I have the following code:

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In Me.lvCustomers
    If CDbl(itm.Tag) <> customer.Id Then Me.lvMerges.Items.Add(itm.Clone)
Next
```

With **Option Strict On** I get the following error:

> Error 2   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' can be
>   called with these arguments:
>       'Public Overridable Function Add(value As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem) As
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem': Option Strict On disallows
>   implicit conversions from 'Object' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'.
>       'Public Overridable Function Add(text As String) As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem': Option Strict On disallows
>   implicit conversions from 'Object' to
>   'String'.

I can do an lvMerges.Items.Add(itm) , which does not throw an error, but then I have to remove it from the lvCustomers listview, which I do not want to do.

Can someone explain how I can make this work properly without turning off **Option Strict?**

Goal is to copy ListviewItem with all SubItems.

Comment: If you use `(ListViewItem)itm.Clone()` does it work then?

Comment: Okay, for some reason I forgot I'm not in c# here... added the correct syntax as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you've received there tells you that with `Option Strict On` on you can't do *implicit* casting from `Object` to `String` or `ListViewItem`.  So you need to do explicit casting instead.

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In Me.lvCustomers
    If CDbl(DirectCast(itm.Tag, String) <> customer.Id Then Me.lvMerges.Items.Add(DirectCast(itm.Clone, ListViewItem))
Next
```

Does that work?